# Spring Boot Implementation into Java project with IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, security, intellij-idea

I am doing a school assignment and having issues Spring Boot, I am not really familiar with Maven or Spring Boot or even where the issue is but I am very lost. I will link the compilation error and the pom.xml file where I believe the issue persists. I will try to answer any questions anyone has, thank you for the help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.snhu</groupId>
   <artifactId>Module2.1</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>Module2.1</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

   <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
             <version>3.7.5</version>
         </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>check</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>check</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>

      </plugins>


   </build>

</project>
```

[image]

........................................

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace as formatted text, and related XML or annotation config.

Comment: Step 1: You're using obsolete versions. Spring Boot is now on 2.7.4 or so. Using https://start.spring.io will help if permissible.

Comment: I do see that I had the same plugin twice and have fixed that with the same issues appearing. I am also not sure what you mean by that Dave. I will try the start spring io

Comment: I have fixed the problem by reuploading the existing project and using java19 instead of java18. Not exactly sure what happened initially, but I did get it working.

Comment: it looks like bean definiton of jsonSchemaConverter. maybe if you shared some codes, we could help.